# I want to show error msg, If user has no access for CustomPermission named "deleteFileAccess"

Tags: apex, exception

The method is

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void deleteSelectedFiles(List<String> contentDocumentIds) {
    try {
        if (!contentDocumentIds.isEmpty() && contentDocumentIds != null) {
            // Check if user has deleteFileAccess custom permission
            Boolean hasDeleteAccess = FeatureManagement.checkPermission('TNZImagePreview__DeleteFileAccess');
            System.debug('User Access' +hasDeleteAccess);
            if (!hasDeleteAccess) {
                throw new AuraHandledException('You do not have permission to delete files.');
            }
            List<ContentDocument> lstCntDocsToDelete = [SELECT Id FROM ContentDocument WHERE Id IN :contentDocumentIds];
            if (!lstCntDocsToDelete.isEmpty()) {
                Database.delete(lstCntDocsToDelete, false);
            }
        } 
    } catch (Exception error) {
        SaveResult result = new SaveResult().addError(error.getMessage()).addErrorToLog(error, null, '', 'FileViewerCC', 'deleteSelectedFiles');
        result.getReturnValue(); // Log Exception
        throw new AuraHandledException('Delete operation cannot be processed. Please contact your system administrator.');
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing in relation to the server-side controller? I assume `TNZImagePreview__DeleteFileAccess` is a valid Custom Permission API name?

Answer (score 0):

The catch in your try-catch is swallowing your custom error. It would only appear in your logs. Also, by using `allOrNone=false` for your DML means that if some records fail to delete, no DMLException will be thrown, and the user will not be told that some records could not be deleted. Also, if you're checking for null or empty lists, make sure you check for null *before* checking if empty. The purpose of the null check is to prevent a NullPointerException, and this check must be done before attempting to access a possibly null object. Your code should look more like this:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void deleteSelectedFiles(List<String> contentDocumentIds) {
    if(contentDocumentIds == null) {
        return;
    }
    List<ContentDocument> lstCntDocsToDelete = [SELECT Id FROM ContentDocument WHERE Id IN :contentDocumentIds];
    if(lstCntDocsToDelete.size() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    Boolean hasDeleteAccess = FeatureManagement.checkPermission('TNZImagePreview__DeleteFileAccess');
    if (!hasDeleteAccess) {
        throw new AuraHandledException('You do not have permission to delete files.');
    }
    try {
        delete as user lstCntDocsToDelete;
    } catch (Exception error) {
        SaveResult result = new SaveResult().addError(error.getMessage()).addErrorToLog(error, null, '', 'FileViewerCC', 'deleteSelectedFiles');
        result.getReturnValue(); // Log Exception
        throw new AuraHandledException('Delete operation cannot be processed. Please contact your system administrator.');
    }
}
```

This will roll back the entire operation if the user doesn't have access, or if one or more files fail to delete. I didn't want to assume too much about the last three statements, so I've left them as is, but you might consider showing the error to the user so they can have more information about what went wrong.